# Difference between had survived, has survived and survived

Tags: grammar

Is it she had survived, she has survived or she survived?

Thanks.

Edit: In one scenario, she's dead, and in another one, she is still alive.

Is "There is no way she could have had survived the attack." - even though she has survived back then, she's now dead from old age.

"There is no way she could have survived the attack." She is still alive.

Can we use just survived in the past simple? Wouldn't that be incorrect because if she had survived, well then there still would be effects in the present (the effects are that she's alive), shouldn't we go with the present perfect?

Comment: It is _she had survived, she has survived,_ and _she survived._ You're welcome.

Comment: How do we know if you don't tell us the context?

Comment: There, I edited it @KateBunting.

Comment: If the woman's subsequent death was not related to the attack that she miraculously survived, it makes no difference whether she is currently alive or not. You can't say _could have had survived_. If the incident was some time in the past, I would suggest _There was no way that she could have survived the attack, and yet [she was alive]_.